# Tablas intermedias y relaciones pivote

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo las siguientes 3 tablas con las relaciones mostradas en la imágen[image: imagen de 3 tablas en MySQL]

En los modelos de `Laravel` estoy definiendo las relaciones con la tabla intermedia de la siguiente manera:

Modelo de la tabla `discounts`;

```
class Discount extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'discounts';

    public function discount_products(){
        $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product', 'product_has_discount', 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Modelo de la tabla `products`

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function product_discounts(){
        $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Discount', 'product_has_discount', 'discount_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

En las migraciones de mis tablas ya tengo las llaves foráneas asignadas correctamente.

Quiero saber si la relación de N:N de las tablas está correcta, si las relaciones que estoy haciendo en Laravel también están bien y como agregaría registros de un lado o el otro para guardar en la tabla intermedia, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Debes realizar una corrección en tus modelos.

Modelo de la tabla discounts:

```
class Discount extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'discounts';

    public function discount_products(){
        $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product', 'product_has_discount', 'product_id', 'dicount_id');
    }
}
```

Modelo de la tabla products:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function product_discounts(){
        $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Discount', 'product_has_discount', 'discount_id', 'product_id');
    }

}
```

Puedes tomar como referencia lo que indica la documentación: [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)